# jquery / javascript - auto delete appended elements after max appends reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I am working on a chat room.

I am currently doing a lot of this:

```
$('#messages').append(readymsg);
```

I want to add some sort of function each time I .append(), so that it will check to see how many appended messages are loaded on the page, and if it's over an amount, it deletes the oldest appended message.

I basically want to make sure my app doesn't get bloated with 1000s of lines of appended messages - and has a maximum of 200 at all times. That way each time .append() happens, if there are 200 messages already appended on the page, it deletes the oldest one, and adds the newest one, so there are still 200 messages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There you go: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: And then, `$(selector).first().remove()`, if you want do delete the first one.

Comment: Here's an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/1zt2jkm6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a FIFO (first in first out) queue.

create an array. and store the reference to the elements there. when 200 are reached, begin removing the oldest items.

```
var queue = new Array();

function addMessage(msg)
{
    queue.push(msg);
    $('#messages').append(msg);

    if ( queue.length > 200 ) {
        var msgToRemove = queue.shift();
        msgToRemove.remove();
    }
}
```

than add messages with:

```
addMessage(readymsg);
```

have in mind that `readymsg` has to be a jQuery element for `.remove()` to work. you can create a jQuery Element from a HTMLElement like this: `$(htmlElement)`

*this will perform better than querying the DOM each time with a jQuery selector*

Comment: I think you might have meant `shift` there! Excellent idea also

Comment: I went with this answer - it worked perfectly - it was important that you noted about the "jQuery Element" $(htmlElement) - as I was not doing that at first, but now it's golden.

Comment: i thought this could be an issue. it is to often generally assumed that everything is jQuery nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide your markup, so I just came up with one for illustration purposes:

```
<div id="messages">
    <div class="message">Chat message 1</div>
    <div class="message">Chat message 2</div>
    <div class="message">Chat message 3</div>
    <div class="message">Chat message 4</div>
    <div class="message">Chat message 5</div>
</div>
<button>New message</button>
```

You can use `length` to check the number of messages in the container:

```
$(function () {
    function addMessage() {
        var msgs = $('#messages .message');
        var count = msgs.length;

        if (count == 10) {
            msgs.first().remove();
        }

        $('<div />', {
            class: 'message'
        })
        .text('Chat message ' + (count + 1).toString())
        .appendTo($('#messages'));
    }

    $('button').on('click', addMessage);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/1zt2jkm6/)

[jQuery .length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

[jQuery .first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

[jQuery .remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

[jQuery .appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)